# Map Data in JSON format. Easily edit a selection of vertices

Tags: gis, geojson

I have the Spanish provinces polygons in a JSON file. For one province, the schema looks like this:

```
{
    "geometry":
    {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates":
        [[[
           [-7702,-4944],
           [-7678,-4979],
           [...,...],
           [-5967,-4077],
           [-5982,-4097]
        ]]]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties":
    {
        "labelrank": 20,
        "code_hasc": "ES.CN",
        ...
        "type": "Comunidad Autónoma",
        "id": "ES.CN"
    }
}
```

I would like to move the vertices of some provinces as described in the image below. The reason for that is that the visualization looks terrible if I project as it is defined in the JSON (half of the map is just empty space).
[image: I want to move the Canary Islands up there]

Using [mapshaper.org](https://mapshaper.org/) I was able to identify the coordinates where I should send the most northern vertex. From here it just a matter of addition to each vertex in all polygons. Before I create a script in Python to do that, I would like to ask the community if there is a software or tool that allows me to select all desired vertices and move them to the desired position, something like moving a selection of nodes using Adobe Illustrator or AutoCad.

Comment: You could add Africa to your map. Alternatively look at QGis to move features and re save

Comment: As I wanted to increase the size of the polygons, adding Africa to the map would do things ever worse. Thanks for the hint about QGis. My problem was exactly that, I was not aware about this kind of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ian Turton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439194/ian-turton) kindly recommended using [QGis](https://www.qgis.org/) for that purpose. The use of the tool is quite straightforward for doing this kind of batch polygon displacements:

1. Open the json file with your geodata
2. In the `Attributes toolbar`,
   click on "Select features" [image: select features icon]
3. Select the features that you want to move:
   [image: selecting features]
4. In the `Vector Toolbar`, click on "Toogle editing" [image: toogle editing icon]
5. Eventually you may need to display the `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar`. Right click on any toolbar and select "Advanced Digitizing Toolbar" under Toolbars [image: advanced digitizing toolbar]
6. With your feature still selected, click on the "Move Feature" icon [image: move feature icon]
7. Click on your selected features and move to your desired location
   [image: features in their new positions]

Because I just wanted the new polygon coordinates for the Canary Islands, I exported the features as GeoJson and replaced accordingly.